# ASP Validation on SQL Results

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, webforms

I have a web form that returns a job number, operation number, and status (Open or Complete).  Normally a result would return:

```
Job_Operation   Job Status  
56248   5294    O   
56249   5294    C   
56253   5294    C   
56250   5294    C   
56251   5294    C   
56252   5294    O   

Then you can select "edit"
Job_Operation   56252
Job 5294
Status  O
edit 

Edit opens up 
Job_Operation   56252
Job 5294
Status  (Open/Close)
Update Cancel
```

The status is the field that returns a list to Open or Close.  I would like to add a validation that would return an error if the previous **operation** is not complete or C or possible a warning that the previous operation is not complete.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should post some code with this question so that others can look for the problem. There isn't enough information here for anyone to guess where the problem might be in your code, and it's unlikely anyone is going to write a complete solution for you (or that they'd be able to from the limited details you've provided).

Answer (score 0):

You didn't really list that much info, but to to check if a sql result was successful you can use a try catch

```
try {
     // (Execute Query) 
}
catch(SqlException ex) {
    // ("there was an sql issue!");
}
catch(Exception ex){
    // ("there was another issue!");
}
```

If you are meaning you don’t want to close the edit window (depending on what you mean by edit opens ???), you can add boolean values on the exit/submit button

```
private bool edited = false;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    try {
         // Execute Query 
         edited = true ; 
     }
    catch(SqlException ex) {
        // ("there was an sql issue!");
    }
    catch(Exception ex){
        // ("there was another issue!");
    }
}
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if(edited){
        // (Close)
    }else {
       // (Don't Close)
    }

}
```